# Run a file with arguments using grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a file called file_1.js which accepts an argument. So i run the file using

"#casperjs file_1.js myarg"

Now I have put the file to run automacitally as a task. Now I run it as

"#grunt casperjs"
which runs file_1.js.

But how do I pass my argument for file_1.js and still make it run with grunt?

Comment: Have a look at [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell). You can run your Casper command as a shell command

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [grunt-casper](https://github.com/iamchrismiller/grunt-casper) task if it has the options you need, otherwise you could use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to run the command.